# if $k = n$, then every vector in $R^n$ can be written as a nontrivial combination of vectors in $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra

if $k = n$, then every vector in $R^n$ can be written as a nontrivial combination of vectors in $S$ ?

Note that $S = {v_1,v_2,..,v_k}$ is a subset of $R^n$.

The problem here we don't know if $S$ is linearly dependent or not.

Is the statement true or false ?

Comment: I mean it sounds like you already answered your question

Answer (score 0):

As you note, if $S$ is linearly independent, then the vectors span the whole space. But note that conversely, if $S$ is not linearly independent, then they only span a smaller dimensional space, and hence not the whole $n$-dimensional vector space.

For an explicit example, take any three vectors on the $x$-$y$ plane in $\mathbb R^3$ to form $S$. Then their span lies inside the $x$-$y$ plane and in particular does not contain, say, $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: I'm in chapter 2 of linear algebra so I didn't fully understand your explanation. I found an easy was to understand it. For example, if we take two vectors in R² [1,0] and [2,0] (linearly dependent) we can't use them to write the vector [0,1]